# Does MapQuest allow us to draw routes on the Map on the free version?

Tags: android, key, mapquest

I have an app that has an old MapQuest key and I wanted to show a route on the Map. However, it didn't work, and on my Callback I got this message:

> This key is not authorized for this service. If you do not have a key,
>   you can obtain a free key by registering at
>   http://developer.mapquest.com.

Does it mean my key is invalid, expired, or maybe I have to pay to have this service?

I visited [MapQuest AppKeys page](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/account/app-keys) today (Mar 29 2015) and it tells me that:

> The ability to create Free & Open AppKeys has been temporarily paused.

Can someone confirm whether routing is allowed with a free key?

Comment: I use their routing service frequently with a free key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a route on a MapQuest map with a Free&Open Key, but you cannot use their service (I mean use Android SDK for routing) because it's not free.

Although, I've created a demo app that get directions from MapQuest'S Web Service (wich is free) and then uses that response to draw the route. You can also request guidance information.

Take a look at my github repo: https://github.com/sebasira/Android-RouteWebService

Hope it helps you! (it was also a headache for me at the time)

Comment: Thanks! But honestly I gave up of MapQuest on this project, too much of a hassle